# Access div from its css properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have this div that I need to change the background color of, however it does not have any class or an id to access it.

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;background-color:#fff;padding:10px;">
</div>
```

The reason I can't add a class is because I am making an extension for the website, not the actual website, and it needs to access it and change the background color (dark mode).

Comment: What criteria are you using for matching this div?

Comment: `div[style*="background-color:#fff;"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector. Be aware that this will only work

- as long as the attribute (`style`) value doesn't change, not in a single character;
- if you need to overwrite any of the inline styles being set in that `div`, you need to make your CSS rule `!important` to beat the inline style specificity.

```css
div[style="margin-bottom:10px;background-color:#fff;padding:10px;"] {
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;background-color:#fff;padding:10px;"></div>
```